# How to prompt 'Authentication Required' dialog box?

Tags: authentication, file-permissions, prompt, browser-security

I want to be able to protect (some of) my website's pages with the 'Aauthentication Required' dialog boxes that pop up in the browser window and ask for username and password when you try to visit a page like http://forums.digitalpoint.com/includes/config.php or a router configuration page. I realize that it is not javascript, perhaps it has to do with file permissions? or not? Please explain.

Comment: It's called "HTTP Basic Authentication" and it works with headers `WWW-Authenticate` (server) and `Authorization` (client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is handled in different ways by each web server. At least tell us which web server/version your are running, and what kind of security you want (basic, digest, ldap based..)

Here you can find the relative doc for Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

IIS 7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx

Best regards.

Comment: Yes i'm running Apache and just want the basic security prompt box that i mentioned above.